# momentjs wrong diff calculation for two times

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm trying to calculate the difference time between to dates with below code:

```js
let start = moment.utc(startTime);  // I'm using utc because time is something like 2021-10-05T08:00:00.000Z
let now = moment(moment.now()); // I'm not using utc method because locale time is important here 

let diff = moment.duration(now.diff(start), "hours");
```

diff return -2 but the real difference is 1

Comment: Diff between UTC and now is the timezone offset of your computer time

Comment: If you are in Iran, there indeed seems to be something wrong. But UTC+03:30
Iran Standard Time (IRST) should give 2:30 hours diff

Comment: @mplungjan It returns -1 hours in diff

Comment: `diff return -2 but the real difference is 1` ?

Comment: What is the current time when you compare `startTime` with the current time (now)? What is your timezone? What is the output of `moment().format()`?

Comment: @alpakyol my current time: 12:02,
timezone: Asia/Iran,
diff in hours return: -1

Comment: @AmirJani `moment.duration()` gives a duration object. How do you get -2, by calling another method? `diff` method without passing unit of measurement results in milliseconds.

Comment: @alpakyol I pass "hours" in diff in second parameter

Comment: @AmirJani You pass `hours` into `duration` method, not into `diff` method according to your question.